# Why is this tkinter function not displaying any pictures

Tags: python, tkinter

I have code to display 2x5 images and change them when I click on them. However, the code I wrote does not display any images in the tkinter windows. Why?

Some details:

- the URLs are working fine

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create a list of images to display
images = ['https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/SsEIJWka3_cYRXXSE8VD3XNOgtOxoZhqW1uB6UFj78eg8gq3G4jAqL4Z_5KwA12aD7Leqp27F653aBkYkRBkEQyeKxfaZPyDx0O8CzWg=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Bawo7r1nPZV6sJ4OHZJHdKV_4Ky59vquAR7KoUXcNZgx9fqTaOW-QaOM9qoyYhOTAopzjt9OIfW06RMwa-9eJW9KjQw=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/tm1DbZrAP0uBM-OJhLwvKir1Le5LglRF_bvbaNi6m-F_pIyttsWQz040soRY9pWA9PgNEYFA_fBkg_keYixRXCAjz9Q=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/AyiKhdEWJ7XmtPXQbRg_kWqKn6mCV07bsuUB01hJHjVVP-ZQFmzjTWt7JIWiQFZbb9l5tKFhVOspmco4lMwqwWImfgg=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FNNTrTASiUR0f49UVUY5bisIM-3RlAbf_AmktgnU_4ou1ZG0juh3pMT1-xpQmtN1R8At4Gq9B4ioSSi4TVrgbCZsmtY=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mAyAjvYjIeAIlByhJx1Huctgeb58y7519XYP38oL1FXarhVlcXW7kxuwayOCFdnwtOp6B6F0HJmmws-Ceo5b_pNSSQs=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gShVRyvLLbwVB8jeIPghCXgr96wxTHaM4zqfmxIWRsUpMhMn38PwuUU13o1mXQzLMt5HFqX761u8Tgo4L_JG1XLATvw=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KA2hIo0BlMDmyQDEC3ixvp9WHgcyJnlAvWtVcZmExh9ocPoZdQGRJh7bZjE2Mx2OGC0Zi3QGHGP0LlmuFgRlIYs36Sgn5G2OD-0MaTo=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/N2m90mImdcoLacUybb_rxcktTwtr0LFhtuzxbSE9elIhElF6jpWngx96_uZ0L1TGNof5pNt4n_Ygb4KYlPTpA9o6788=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1pTfYJlLwVTifKj4PlsWPyAg4PcIVBAiVvB8sameSnmm7HRd056abNUIRq33rgry7u9t-ju-eHOnbfqQpK4q_8IwzIXZ4WgrqZW9l7U=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/0bgOiMrBM2GuhW_pNeQW711GuB3kD7Gq7AILGHaJGeWKa1Fu1hUJGpOjvSpiP_XpgRlC4jVmH0Z1233PEPMJTfNRR7Q=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/x9NFmu-RbZ_9M5BK_hOzQRdVj4pu7p--y_IYwDK46lDPzQtTIO9AlBV_ObgQiY7GeWE0ZfNjMSyrCWgnwL4MCasQZQ=s0']

# Create a variable to keep track of the current image
current_image = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

# Create a grid of labels to display the images
image_grid = [[tk.Label(root) for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(2)]

# Function to change the image
def change_image(x,y):
    global current_image
    current_image[x*5+y] += 1
    if current_image[x*5+y] >= len(images):
        current_image[x*5+y] = 0
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(images[current_image[x*5+y]]).content))
    image = image.resize((256,256))
    print(image)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    image_grid[x][y].config(image=photo)
    image_grid[x][y].image = photo

# Bind labels to the function
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(5):
        image_grid[i][j].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, x=i, y=j: change_image(x,y))
        image_grid[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j)

# Start the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, you used `Label` without a text and they were just not visible. I suggest you use `Button` instead. Your `x` and `y` in `change_image` update correctly, but `images[current_image[x*5+y]]` always pointed to the same image. I simplified your code and removed the global variable:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import requests
from io import BytesIO

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create a list of images to display
images = ['https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/SsEIJWka3_cYRXXSE8VD3XNOgtOxoZhqW1uB6UFj78eg8gq3G4jAqL4Z_5KwA12aD7Leqp27F653aBkYkRBkEQyeKxfaZPyDx0O8CzWg=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Bawo7r1nPZV6sJ4OHZJHdKV_4Ky59vquAR7KoUXcNZgx9fqTaOW-QaOM9qoyYhOTAopzjt9OIfW06RMwa-9eJW9KjQw=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/tm1DbZrAP0uBM-OJhLwvKir1Le5LglRF_bvbaNi6m-F_pIyttsWQz040soRY9pWA9PgNEYFA_fBkg_keYixRXCAjz9Q=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/AyiKhdEWJ7XmtPXQbRg_kWqKn6mCV07bsuUB01hJHjVVP-ZQFmzjTWt7JIWiQFZbb9l5tKFhVOspmco4lMwqwWImfgg=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FNNTrTASiUR0f49UVUY5bisIM-3RlAbf_AmktgnU_4ou1ZG0juh3pMT1-xpQmtN1R8At4Gq9B4ioSSi4TVrgbCZsmtY=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mAyAjvYjIeAIlByhJx1Huctgeb58y7519XYP38oL1FXarhVlcXW7kxuwayOCFdnwtOp6B6F0HJmmws-Ceo5b_pNSSQs=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gShVRyvLLbwVB8jeIPghCXgr96wxTHaM4zqfmxIWRsUpMhMn38PwuUU13o1mXQzLMt5HFqX761u8Tgo4L_JG1XLATvw=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KA2hIo0BlMDmyQDEC3ixvp9WHgcyJnlAvWtVcZmExh9ocPoZdQGRJh7bZjE2Mx2OGC0Zi3QGHGP0LlmuFgRlIYs36Sgn5G2OD-0MaTo=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/N2m90mImdcoLacUybb_rxcktTwtr0LFhtuzxbSE9elIhElF6jpWngx96_uZ0L1TGNof5pNt4n_Ygb4KYlPTpA9o6788=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1pTfYJlLwVTifKj4PlsWPyAg4PcIVBAiVvB8sameSnmm7HRd056abNUIRq33rgry7u9t-ju-eHOnbfqQpK4q_8IwzIXZ4WgrqZW9l7U=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/0bgOiMrBM2GuhW_pNeQW711GuB3kD7Gq7AILGHaJGeWKa1Fu1hUJGpOjvSpiP_XpgRlC4jVmH0Z1233PEPMJTfNRR7Q=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/x9NFmu-RbZ_9M5BK_hOzQRdVj4pu7p--y_IYwDK46lDPzQtTIO9AlBV_ObgQiY7GeWE0ZfNjMSyrCWgnwL4MCasQZQ=s0']

# Create a grid of labels to display the images
image_grid = [[tk.Button(root, text=f"Button {x} {y}") for x in range(5)] for y in range(2)]

# Function to change the image
def change_image(x,y):
    print(f"Changing image to: {x} {y} (index: {x*5+y}): {images[x*5+y]}")
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(images[x*5+y]).content))
    image = image.resize((256, 256))
    print(image)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    image_grid[x][y].config(image=photo)
    image_grid[x][y].image = photo

# Bind labels to the function
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(5):
        image_grid[i][j].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, x=i, y=j: change_image(x,y))
        image_grid[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j)

# Start the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This modifies the program's behavior. I think OP's intent was to cycle through all images inside each label... I might be wrong though.

Comment: @Tranbi ah, you might be right..!

Answer (score 1):

The Images will only display after you click on a label. And your labels are all very small when you initialize your window. Set a bigger window and use `sticky` in grid to get bigger cells (you can even set a border to the labels to see where exactly you're clicking):

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO
import requests

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1280x720')

# Create a list of images to display
images = ['https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/SsEIJWka3_cYRXXSE8VD3XNOgtOxoZhqW1uB6UFj78eg8gq3G4jAqL4Z_5KwA12aD7Leqp27F653aBkYkRBkEQyeKxfaZPyDx0O8CzWg=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Bawo7r1nPZV6sJ4OHZJHdKV_4Ky59vquAR7KoUXcNZgx9fqTaOW-QaOM9qoyYhOTAopzjt9OIfW06RMwa-9eJW9KjQw=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/tm1DbZrAP0uBM-OJhLwvKir1Le5LglRF_bvbaNi6m-F_pIyttsWQz040soRY9pWA9PgNEYFA_fBkg_keYixRXCAjz9Q=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/AyiKhdEWJ7XmtPXQbRg_kWqKn6mCV07bsuUB01hJHjVVP-ZQFmzjTWt7JIWiQFZbb9l5tKFhVOspmco4lMwqwWImfgg=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FNNTrTASiUR0f49UVUY5bisIM-3RlAbf_AmktgnU_4ou1ZG0juh3pMT1-xpQmtN1R8At4Gq9B4ioSSi4TVrgbCZsmtY=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mAyAjvYjIeAIlByhJx1Huctgeb58y7519XYP38oL1FXarhVlcXW7kxuwayOCFdnwtOp6B6F0HJmmws-Ceo5b_pNSSQs=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gShVRyvLLbwVB8jeIPghCXgr96wxTHaM4zqfmxIWRsUpMhMn38PwuUU13o1mXQzLMt5HFqX761u8Tgo4L_JG1XLATvw=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KA2hIo0BlMDmyQDEC3ixvp9WHgcyJnlAvWtVcZmExh9ocPoZdQGRJh7bZjE2Mx2OGC0Zi3QGHGP0LlmuFgRlIYs36Sgn5G2OD-0MaTo=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/N2m90mImdcoLacUybb_rxcktTwtr0LFhtuzxbSE9elIhElF6jpWngx96_uZ0L1TGNof5pNt4n_Ygb4KYlPTpA9o6788=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1pTfYJlLwVTifKj4PlsWPyAg4PcIVBAiVvB8sameSnmm7HRd056abNUIRq33rgry7u9t-ju-eHOnbfqQpK4q_8IwzIXZ4WgrqZW9l7U=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/0bgOiMrBM2GuhW_pNeQW711GuB3kD7Gq7AILGHaJGeWKa1Fu1hUJGpOjvSpiP_XpgRlC4jVmH0Z1233PEPMJTfNRR7Q=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/x9NFmu-RbZ_9M5BK_hOzQRdVj4pu7p--y_IYwDK46lDPzQtTIO9AlBV_ObgQiY7GeWE0ZfNjMSyrCWgnwL4MCasQZQ=s0']

# Create a variable to keep track of the current image
current_image = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

# Create a grid of labels to display the images
image_grid = [[tk.Label(root, borderwidth=2, relief="groove") for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(2)]

# Function to change the image
def change_image(x,y):
    global current_image
    current_image[x*5+y] += 1
    if current_image[x*5+y] >= len(images):
        current_image[x*5+y] = 0
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(images[current_image[x*5+y]]).content))
    image = image.resize((256,256))
    print(image)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    image_grid[x][y].config(image=photo)
    image_grid[x][y].image = photo

# Bind labels to the function
for i in range(2):
    root.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
    for j in range(5):
        root.columnconfigure(j, weight=1)
        image_grid[i][j].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, x=i, y=j: change_image(x,y))
        image_grid[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew")

# Start the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Note: setting `rowconfigure`/`columnconfigure` ensures that the cells have the same dimension, you might want to use it in `change_image` as well

Comment: add a placeholder image `image = Image.new('RGBA', (256, 256)); photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)` to avoid needing the `root.geometry` which enforces a size.

Comment: What's wrong with setting a window size on startup? it can be resized anyway...

Comment: nothing "wrong", it will just look better.

Comment: It seems that it would make the code more complicated and not really affect the window size on startup (which bugs me tbh). But maybe I'm missing something... Feel free to suggest your own answer!

Answer (score 1):

your issue is that the labels start with a zero width and height because they are empty, you could set a placeholder image on startup to make the GUI fit exactly perfect around it.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO
import requests

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create a list of images to display
images = ['https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/SsEIJWka3_cYRXXSE8VD3XNOgtOxoZhqW1uB6UFj78eg8gq3G4jAqL4Z_5KwA12aD7Leqp27F653aBkYkRBkEQyeKxfaZPyDx0O8CzWg=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Bawo7r1nPZV6sJ4OHZJHdKV_4Ky59vquAR7KoUXcNZgx9fqTaOW-QaOM9qoyYhOTAopzjt9OIfW06RMwa-9eJW9KjQw=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/tm1DbZrAP0uBM-OJhLwvKir1Le5LglRF_bvbaNi6m-F_pIyttsWQz040soRY9pWA9PgNEYFA_fBkg_keYixRXCAjz9Q=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/AyiKhdEWJ7XmtPXQbRg_kWqKn6mCV07bsuUB01hJHjVVP-ZQFmzjTWt7JIWiQFZbb9l5tKFhVOspmco4lMwqwWImfgg=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FNNTrTASiUR0f49UVUY5bisIM-3RlAbf_AmktgnU_4ou1ZG0juh3pMT1-xpQmtN1R8At4Gq9B4ioSSi4TVrgbCZsmtY=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mAyAjvYjIeAIlByhJx1Huctgeb58y7519XYP38oL1FXarhVlcXW7kxuwayOCFdnwtOp6B6F0HJmmws-Ceo5b_pNSSQs=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gShVRyvLLbwVB8jeIPghCXgr96wxTHaM4zqfmxIWRsUpMhMn38PwuUU13o1mXQzLMt5HFqX761u8Tgo4L_JG1XLATvw=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KA2hIo0BlMDmyQDEC3ixvp9WHgcyJnlAvWtVcZmExh9ocPoZdQGRJh7bZjE2Mx2OGC0Zi3QGHGP0LlmuFgRlIYs36Sgn5G2OD-0MaTo=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/N2m90mImdcoLacUybb_rxcktTwtr0LFhtuzxbSE9elIhElF6jpWngx96_uZ0L1TGNof5pNt4n_Ygb4KYlPTpA9o6788=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1pTfYJlLwVTifKj4PlsWPyAg4PcIVBAiVvB8sameSnmm7HRd056abNUIRq33rgry7u9t-ju-eHOnbfqQpK4q_8IwzIXZ4WgrqZW9l7U=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/0bgOiMrBM2GuhW_pNeQW711GuB3kD7Gq7AILGHaJGeWKa1Fu1hUJGpOjvSpiP_XpgRlC4jVmH0Z1233PEPMJTfNRR7Q=s0',
 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/x9NFmu-RbZ_9M5BK_hOzQRdVj4pu7p--y_IYwDK46lDPzQtTIO9AlBV_ObgQiY7GeWE0ZfNjMSyrCWgnwL4MCasQZQ=s0']

# Create a variable to keep track of the current image
current_image = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

# Create a grid of labels to display the images
image = Image.new('RGBA', (256, 256))
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
image_grid = [[tk.Label(root, image=photo, borderwidth=2, relief="groove") for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(2)]

# Function to change the image
def change_image(x,y):
    global current_image
    current_image[x*5+y] += 1
    if current_image[x*5+y] >= len(images):
        current_image[x*5+y] = 0
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(images[current_image[x*5+y]]).content))
    image = image.resize((256,256))
    print(image)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    image_grid[x][y].config(image=photo)
    image_grid[x][y].image = photo

# Bind labels to the function
for i in range(2):
    root.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
    for j in range(5):
        root.columnconfigure(j, weight=1)
        image_grid[i][j].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, x=i, y=j: change_image(x,y))
        image_grid[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j)

# Start the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Now I get it! kwarg `image=photo` for `Label` is what I missed ;-)